# About a clean common method

Tags: swift

It is a process to slide the screen when the keyboard appears, but this process is described by many controllers. 
The processing in if and else changes according to each controller.
Is there a way to cleanly share it?
Also, where and how should we commonize?

```
func keyboardWillChangeFrame(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let endFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        var keyboardHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - endFrame.origin.y
        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            if keyboardHeight > 0 {
                view.addGestureRecognizer(ui.viewTapGesture)
                ui.isHiddenSubmitBtn(false)
                ui.isHiddenTextCount(false)
                keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom + ui.submitBtn.frame.height + 8
            } else {
                view.removeGestureRecognizer(ui.viewTapGesture)
                ui.isHiddenSubmitBtn(true)
                ui.isHiddenTextCount(true)
            }
        }
        ui.textViewBottomConstraint.constant = -keyboardHeight - 8
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest (though this is not directly relevant) that what you're doing is not a very good way to deal cleanly with the keyboard. Instead, put your interface into a scroll view (even if the user cannot normally scroll it). This is makes it trivial to scroll automatically to reveal something when the user tries to edit it, and gives the user an automatic way to remove the keyboard by dragging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class and protocols, example code below

```
// Firstly Create Notifier Keyboard
class KeyboardNotifier: NSObject {

    // We notify this closures
    var keyboardPresent: ((_ height: CGFloat) -> Void)?
    var keyboardDismiss: ((_ height: CGFloat) -> Void)?

    // Add Notification
    func listenKeyboard() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillChangeFramex(_:)),
                                               name: UIApplication.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    // Handle Notification and call closures
    @objc func keyboardWillChangeFramex(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let endFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let keyboardHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - endFrame.origin.y
            if #available(iOS 11, *) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    if keyboardHeight > 0 {
                        self?.keyboardPresent?(keyboardHeight)
                    } else {
                        self?.keyboardDismiss?(keyboardHeight)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Create a listener protocol
protocol KeyboardListener {
    func keyboardPresent(_ height: CGFloat)
    func keyboardDismiss(_ height: CGFloat)
    var keyboardNotifier: KeyboardNotifier! { get set }
}

// We need a extension for we don't want all viewController
extension KeyboardListener where Self: UIViewController  {

    // We need call this function viewDidLoad later
    func listenKeyboard(keyboardNotifier: KeyboardNotifier) {
        keyboardNotifier.keyboardDismiss = { [weak self] height in
            self?.keyboardDismiss(height)
        }
        keyboardNotifier.keyboardPresent = { [weak self] height in
            self?.keyboardPresent(height)
        }
    }

}

// A XViewController want's to listen keyboard
class XViewController: UIViewController, KeyboardListener {
    var keyboardNotifier: KeyboardNotifier!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // We need instance for life cycle
        keyboardNotifier = KeyboardNotifier()
        listenKeyboard(keyboardNotifier: keyboardNotifier)
    }


    func keyboardPresent(_ height: CGFloat) {
        // TODO UI
    }

    func keyboardDismiss(_ height: CGFloat) {
        // TODO UI
    }

}
// If you want all viewController listen keyboard
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, KeyboardListener {
    var keyboardNotifier: KeyboardNotifier!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // We need instance for life cycle
        keyboardNotifier = KeyboardNotifier()
        listenKeyboard(keyboardNotifier: keyboardNotifier)
    }

    func keyboardPresent(_ height: CGFloat) {

    }

    func keyboardDismiss(_ height: CGFloat) {

    }
}
// This Y ViewController from BaseViewController
class YViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func keyboardPresent(_ height: CGFloat) {

    }

    override func keyboardDismiss(_ height: CGFloat) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! And I also studied!